# python string replace to \u

Tags: python

I have a string.

```
m = 'I have two element. <U+2F3E> and <U+2F8F>'
```

I want to m replace to:

```
m = 'I have two element. \u2F3E and \u2F8F' # utf-8
```

my code:

```
import re

p1 = re.compile('<U+\+') # start "<"
p2 = re.compile('>+')    # end   ">"
m = 'I have two element. <U+2F3E> and <U+2F8F>'

out = pattern.sub('\\u', m) # like: 'I have two element. \u2F3E> and \u2F8F>'
```

but I get this error message:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

How can I fix it. thanks.

Comment: That's not UTF-8. Strings in Python are just Unicode, there is no encoding involved. Some people seem to mistakenly believe that the `\u1234` notation is UTF-8 but it's not; this is how Python (and e.g. Javascript) encodes a Unicode code point as pure ASCII in source files.

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace the literal string `<U+1234>` with the literal string `\u1234` or do you mean you want to replace `<U+1234>` with the actual Unicode code point?

Comment: @tripleee Thanks your comment. I want to replace <U+1234> with the actual Unicode code 

Comment: Several of the answers you received show you how to replace with literal `\u`; you really want to be explicit about these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single regular expression to find the strings and pull out the part you want to use in the replacement.

The reason you get an error is that `'\\u'` passes the literal string `\u` to the regex engine, which tries to parse it as a Unicode character, and fails; the `\u` needs to be followed by exactly four hex digits to form a valid Unicode code point. But you are still approaching this as if you wanted to replace with a literal string, which as per your clarifying comment is wrong.

```py
import re

m = re.sub(r'<U\+([0-9a-fA-F]{4})>', lambda x: chr(int(x.group(1), 16)), m)
```

The `lambda` receives the match object as its argument; `x.group(1)` pulls out the first parenthesized group, and `chr(int(that, 16))` produces the corresponding literal character.

If you *actually* want to produce the UTF-8 encoding of that, that's easy, too:

```py
>>> re.sub(r'<U\+([0-9a-fA-F]{4})>', lambda x: chr(int(x.group(1), 16)), 'I have two element. <U+2F3E> and <U+2F8F>')
'I have two element. ⼾ and ⾏'
>>> re.sub(r'<U\+([0-9a-fA-F]{4})>', lambda x: chr(int(x.group(1), 16)), 'I have two element. <U+2F3E> and <U+2F8F>').encode('utf-8')
b'I have two element. \xe2\xbc\xbe and \xe2\xbe\x8f'
```

As you can see, the UTF-8 encoding is a sequence of bytes which do not correspond to printable characters at all. (Well, they could be printed in some other encodings; but then that's just [mojibake.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)

Answer (score 5):

```py
import re

m = 'I have two element. <U+2F3E> and <U+2F8F>'

print(re.sub(r'<U\+(\w+)>', r"\\u\1", m))

# I have two element. \u2F3E and \u2F8F
```

Comment: In the string of the `repl` parameter passed to `re.sub()`, you can use `\ ` plus the group number to get the corresponding group number data, such as `\1` for the group number 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
m.replace('<U+', '\u')
m.replace('>',' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code, this might help

```
m = m.replace('<U+', '\\u').replace('>',' ')
```